# The number of equivalence classes of finite symmetric difference relation

Tags: combinatorics, set-theory, equivalence-relations

Let $\Sigma$ be an infinite set.

Let $A,B \subseteq \Sigma$ be of finite symmetric difference iff they have a finite difference, more formally:

> $A \sim B$ iff $|A \Delta B| \in \mathbb{N}$

How many equivalence classes does $\sim$ have?

Comment: What you’re calling *difference* is generally called *symmetric difference*.

Comment: @Brian, thanks, I added "symmetric".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A \subseteq \Sigma$ be an arbitrary set. Then the size of $[A]$ (the equivalence class of $A$) is equal to the number of finite subsets of $\Sigma$. The number of finite subsets of $\Sigma$ is of the same cardinality as $\Sigma$ since $\Sigma$ is an infinite set. Therefore we have $|[A]| = |\Sigma|$ for all $A$.

Let $I$ be the set of equivalence classes. We have $P(\Sigma) = \bigcup_{[A]\in I} [A]$ and distinct equivalence classes are disjoint. Therefore we have $2^{|\Sigma|} = |P(\Sigma)| = |\bigcup_{[A]\in I} [A]| = |I| |\Sigma|$. Thus by cardinal arithmetic we have $|I| = 2^{|\Sigma|}$.

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: Why is $[A]$ equal to the number of finite subsets of $\Sigma$?

Comment: $f(S) = A \Delta S$. Then $f(S) \Delta A = S$. So $f$ is a bijective, mapping any finite subset $S$ to a $B$ in equivalence class of A.